# How can I use the correct Max function in my code?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Goodmorning,

I have the same nodes in my code and they all got other percentages.. I just want the node with the highest percentage. I can't seem to get my code right. Is there any way to use the max function on this?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine/cac:TaxTotal/cac:TaxSubtotal/cac:TaxCategory">
     <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(cbc:Percent) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(cbc:Percent,'00')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="21"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried the code above. Now I get result 0021212121. So the code selects all of the fields in cbc:Percent.

```
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>1</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity/>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</LineExtensionAmount>
<OrderLineReference>
<LineID>1</LineID>
<OrderReference>
<ID>351450.27</ID>
</OrderReference>
</OrderLineReference>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>NA</ID>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme/>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>685000 / 08.0005 /filiaal: 2666 / ref1: 
 `351450.27</Description>`
<SellersItemIdentification>
<ID/>
</SellersItemIdentification>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</PriceAmount>
<BaseQuantity>1</BaseQuantity>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>2</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>2</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">19.76</LineExtensionAmount>
<OrderLineReference>
<LineID>2</LineID>
<OrderReference>
<ID>351450.27</ID>
</OrderReference>
</OrderLineReference>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">4.15</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">19.76</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">4.15</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>Excluding</ID>
<Percent>21</Percent>
<TaxScheme/>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>BLABLA</Description>
<SellersItemIdentification>
<ID>96184323</ID>
</SellersItemIdentification>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">9.88</PriceAmount>
<BaseQuantity>1</BaseQuantity>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>3</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>10</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">12.00</LineExtensionAmount>
<OrderLineReference>
<LineID>3</LineID>
<OrderReference>
<ID>351450.27</ID>
</OrderReference>
</OrderLineReference>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">2.52</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">12.00</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">2.52</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>Excluding</ID>
<Percent>21</Percent>
<TaxScheme/>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>KONS. 2H LICHT D37</Description>
<SellersItemIdentification>
<ID>7040237023</ID>
</SellersItemIdentification>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">3.39</PriceAmount>
<BaseQuantity>1</BaseQuantity>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>4</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>10</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">44.10</LineExtensionAmount>
<OrderLineReference>
<LineID>4</LineID>
<OrderReference>
<ID>351450.27</ID>
</OrderReference>
</OrderLineReference>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">9.26</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">44.10</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">9.26</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>Excluding</ID>
<Percent>21</Percent>
<TaxScheme/>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>blabla</Description>
<SellersItemIdentification>
<ID>7041037023</ID>
</SellersItemIdentification>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">12.37</PriceAmount>
<BaseQuantity>1</BaseQuantity>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>5</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>1</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">25.00</LineExtensionAmount>
<OrderLineReference>
<LineID>6</LineID>
<OrderReference>
<ID>351450.27</ID>
</OrderReference>
</OrderLineReference>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">5.25</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">25.00</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">5.25</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>Excluding</ID>
<Percent>21</Percent>
<TaxScheme/>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>blabla</Description>
<SellersItemIdentification>
<ID>VRACHT</ID>
</SellersItemIdentification>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">25.00</PriceAmount>
<BaseQuantity>1</BaseQuantity>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
```

In this code, the highest percentage is 21, so I just want 21 as result and not all the results in the nodes.. Can somebody help me with the code please??

Comment: If you move to XSLT 2 with XPath 2 then you have a `max` function so look at https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/max.html for instance. To find a maximum value in XSLT 1 you need to sort and take the last for ascending or first item for descending sort order.

Comment: In fact that technique can't be done in pure XSLT 1.0 -- it needs the (widely but not universally available) `xx:node-set()` extension to turn the result of the sort operation into a node-set that you can index into.

Comment: Can you help me with how I can do that? Can I put a code into my excisting code with selecting only the last 2 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this without an extension function. Your current code seems to suggest you can have more than one `Percent` (or maybe none at all). If so, try this template

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine/cac:TaxTotal/cac:TaxSubtotal/cac:TaxCategory">
    <xsl:sort select="cbc:Percent * (count(cbc:Percent) = 1) + 21 * (1 - (count(cbc:Percent) = 1))" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(cbc:Percent) = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(cbc:Percent,'00')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="21"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If you could only ever have zero or one percent, you could simplify it to this...

```
<xsl:sort select="cbc:Percent * count(cbc:Percent) + 21 * count(cbc:Percent)" order="descending" />
```

And, of course, if all nodes always had a single `Percent` you could just do this....

```
<xsl:sort select="cbc:Percent" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!! All nodes have a single percent, so I used the last rule for sorting. That did it for me. Thank you very very much.. This saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Just because this will not fit in comments, I would refactor the solution this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable 
     name="vTaxCategory"
     select="/x:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine/cac:TaxTotal/cac:TaxSubtotal/cac:TaxCategory"/>
  <xsl:variable 
     name="vTaxCategoryWithNoPercent"
     select="$vTaxCategory[not(cbc:Percent)]"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$vTaxCategory/cbc:Percent">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$vTaxCategoryWithNoPercent and 21 > . ">21</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(cbc:Percent,'00')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Just get the maximum and then replace it in case there is a missing `Percent` and it is less than 21.